# how to integrate new data with existing data in a column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i want to integrate data with exiting data in a column in phpmyadmin.

for example i have a table which has a column (ticket_number).

And its exiting value is 234 and want to add '1' before 234 so that the value will be 1234.
this below written code not working for this.

```
UPDATE ticket
SET `ticket_number`+= '1';
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `CONCAT`:

```
UPDATE ticket
SET ticket_number = CONCAT(1,ticket_number)
```

Because if you add up the "1" directly you'll get 235 not 1234...

Comment: thanks @darkajax . now i got my answer. once again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Probably something like this:

```
UPDATE ticket
SET ticket_number = '1' + ticket_number
```

MySQL doesn't understand +=

Comment: As a matter of fact, MySQL doesn't understand `+` as a concatenation operator either, although basically the idea should now be clear.

Answer (score 2):

Because your data is probably stored as an integer, you would need to add 1000 not 1.

You could provide some more information about the field type.